# Linker error: "linker input file unused because linking not done", undefined reference to a function in that file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, linker-errors

I'm having trouble with the linking of my files.

Basically, my program consists of:

- The main program, `gen1`.
- `gen1` - receives input sends to `str2value` for
  processing, outputs results `str2value`, breaks input into tokens
  using "tokenizer" determines what sort of processing to do to each
  token, and passes them off to `str2num`, or `str2cmd`. It then returns an
  array of the results.
- `str2num` - does some processing
- `str2cmd` - ditto
- `author.py` - a python script that generates `str2cmd.c` and `str2cmd.h` from a header `cmdTable.h`.

I'm pretty sure I have my includes right, I've checked a couple of times. I've also checked that there are no conditions `#ifndef` wrong in the headers.

Here is my Makefile:

```
#CPP = g++ -lserial
CPP = g++ -DTESTMODE
C= gcc
DEFINES = LURC
CFLAGS = -Wall -fshort-enums -D$(DEFINES)
PROJECTFILES = gen1.cpp str2value.o

STR2VALUEFILES = str2value.cpp str2cmd.o str2num.o tokenizer.o str2value.h

gen1 : $(PROJECTFILES)
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -o gen1 $(PROJECTFILES)



str2value.o : $(STR2VALUEFILES)
#       echo "str2value"
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $(STR2VALUEFILES)

str2num.o: str2num.cpp  str2value.h str2num.hpp
         $(C) $(CFLAGS) -c $^


tokenizer.o: tokenizer.cpp tokenizer.hpp
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

str2cmd.o : authorCMDs.py cmdTable.h
        python authorCMDs.py cmdTable.h str2cmd #this uses the gcc -E cmdTable.h -DLURC
        $(C) $(CFLAGS) -c str2cmd.c str2cmd.h

#TODO: add a thing that checks str2cmd.h/.c has not been modified by hand



.PHONEY: clean
clean:
        rm *.o

.PHONEY: all
all:
        clear
        make clean
        make
```

Here is the output I recieve from make all:

```
make clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/frames/LURC/gen1/gen1Source'
rm *.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/frames/LURC/gen1/gen1Source'
make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/frames/LURC/gen1/gen1Source'
python authorCMDs.py cmdTable.h str2cmd #this uses the gcc -E cmdTable.h -DLURC
str2cmd.c and str2cmd.h, generated from cmdTable.h

gcc  -Wall -fshort-enums -DLURC -c str2cmd.c str2cmd.h
gcc  -Wall -fshort-enums -DLURC -c str2num.cpp str2value.h str2num.hpp
g++ -DTESTMODE -Wall -fshort-enums -DLURC -c tokenizer.cpp tokenizer.hpp
g++ -DTESTMODE -Wall -fshort-enums -DLURC -c str2value.cpp str2cmd.o str2num.o tokenizer.o str2value.h
g++: str2cmd.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: str2num.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: tokenizer.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ -DTESTMODE -Wall -fshort-enums -DLURC -o gen1 gen1.cpp str2value.o
str2value.o: In function `getValue(char*)':
str2value.cpp:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `str2cmd(char*)'
str2value.cpp:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `str2num(char*)'
str2value.o: In function `getAllValues(char*)':
str2value.cpp:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `tokenizer::tokenizer(char*)'
str2value.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `tokenizer::getNumTokens(char const*)'
str2value.cpp:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `tokenizer::getNextToken(char const*)'
str2value.cpp:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `tokenizer::getNumTokens(char const*)'
str2value.cpp:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `tokenizer::~tokenizer()'
str2value.cpp:(.text+0x25b): undefined reference to `tokenizer::~tokenizer()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [gen1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/frames/LURC/gen1/gen1Source'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions about what this is about? `STR2VALUESFILES` has all the object files I need, to define the missing functions.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think you are confused about how the compiler puts things together. When you use `-c` flag, i.e. no linking is done, the input is C++ code, and the output is object code. The `.o` files thus don't mix with `-c`, and compiler warns you about that. Symbols from object file are *not* moved to other object files like that.

All object files should be on the final linker invocation, which is not the case here, so linker (called via `g++` front-end) complains about missing symbols.

Here's a small example (calling `g++` explicitly for clarity):

```
PROG ?= myprog
OBJS = worker.o main.o

all: $(PROG)

.cpp.o:
        g++ -Wall -pedantic -ggdb -O2 -c -o $@ $<

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
        g++ -Wall -pedantic -ggdb -O2 -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

There's also [`makedepend`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/makedepend/) utility that comes with X11 - helps a lot with source code dependencies. You might also want to look at the `-M` `gcc` option for building `make` rules.

Comment: how can i build an object file, out of other object files, then?
gen1 has no direct dependancies with str2num str2cmd or tokenizer

Comment: You compile each `.cpp` file individually, then link all resulting `.o` files together. I added a simple `make` example.

Comment: Forgot to mention - manage dependencies via header files, not object files.

Comment: I'm having  trouble followign your example.
I've never seen $@, @< or you use of .cpp.o

Comment: `.cpp.o` rule tells `make` how to build a file with `.o` suffix out of corresponding file with `.cpp` suffix (say, how to produce `main.o` out of `main.cpp`) The `$<` is the "input" of the rule, `$@` is the "output" (again, `$<` would be `main.cpp`, `$@` would be `main.o`) These are *builtin variables* of `make`.

Comment: I changed the line which was previosly not working - compiling objects into an object isn't allowed.
into consolidating obects into a library.
It works, thanks.

Comment: If you want to link a bunch of object files into a single resulting object file, you can create a static lib out of them.  That'll save you large compile times if you only changed one file or whatever.  On *nix: `ar -rc all_objects.a *.o`.  Then you can just `gcc -o test test.c all_objects.a`.  Advantage of this is that static linking automatically "trims the fat" so to speak, so you only pay for what you use.  For instance, if your source code file doesn't use anything from `all_objects.a`, the resulting binary should be the same size as if you didn't include it at all.