# linker input file unused because linking not done

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

I am trying to compile a simple program on cygwin. I don't know why my IDE (Netbeans) trying to use a '-c' flag. In Project Properties->C++ compiler->Additional options i have no '-c' flag. How to resolve this?

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf

make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_3'
rm -f -r build/Release
rm -f dist/Release/Cygwin-Windows/cppapplication_3.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_3'


CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_3'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/Cygwin-Windows/cppapplication_3.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_3'
mkdir -p build/Release/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f build/Release/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d
i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -E   -c -O2 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/local/apr -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Release/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Release/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Release/Cygwin-Windows
i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -E    -o dist/Release/Cygwin-Windows/cppapplication_3 build/Release/Cygwin-Windows/main.o 
i686-pc-mingw32-g++: warning: build/Release/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_3'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_3'


BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

Comment: That -E option is curious. man:"-E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper." The -c option is normal. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395158/linker-error-linker-input-file-unused-because-linking-not-done-undefined-ref

Comment: Ah... I wonder why the main.o file would not generate an error if that's the C++ code after preprocessor. It should be incompatible input to the linker!?

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` flag isn't an additional flag, it's one of the basic flags your IDE uses to tell the compiler to compile a source file (eg. `main.cpp`) into and object file (eg. `main.o`). It's also not used on the command that gives you the warning message.

However, what is an additional flag is the `-E` flag that you can see being used both times `g++` is invoked. According to the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-E-81) this is what the `-E` flag does:

> Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper. The output is in the form
>   of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output.
>
> Input files that don't require preprocessing are ignored

You don't see the preprocessed source code because the `-o` option that your IDE supplied told it to put it into a file instead. If you look at `build/Release/Cygwin-Windows/main.o` you'll find that it's a text file that contains the result of passing your source code through the preprocessor. However it's actually supposed to be a binary file, the result of compiling your code in an object file.

So hopefully the solution should be obvious, remove the `-E` flag from the additional options.