# Pocketsphinx - what is the proper way to link/include library using Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, path, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am working on a project that uses pocketsphinx for the first time, and I am having alot of trouble getting my program to compile. I have edited this question a bit since Nikolay has helped me pinpoint where my problem is, but I am still having trouble getting my program to compile.

I have attempted to split up the compilation flags from the pocketsphinx docs to make them Makefile-friendly, but I must be putting them in the wrong place. I am getting the error:

```
src/server/server.c:41:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MODELDIR'
                         "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
                                 ^
1 error generated.
```

I would share my server.c, but the error message tells me that the error isn't in my file -- something must not have linked properly, because I should be able to use `MODELDIR`

At this point I am guessing that I put the `-DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\"` in the wrong place. I have been searching on google, and I can't find anything that explains where to put `-DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\"`

This is how I am declaring the `MODELDIR` variable in my Makefile:

`MODELDIR = $(shell pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx)`

And this is where I am using it to compile:

```
$(NAME_SV): $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM)
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling $(NAME_SV)...\033[0m"
    @gcc $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM) $(LINK) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_LIBS) -lm -o $(NAME_SV)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] $(NAME_SV) Created.\033[0m\n"
```

And for perspective, here is my entire Makefile:

```
NAME_CL = client
NAME_SV = server
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra -g
MODELDIR = $(shell pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx)
SPHX_FLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags pocketsphinx sphinxbase)
SPHX_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase)

# SV - Server specific files
# CL - Client specific files
# HL - Files containing helper functions used in both client and server
# CM - Files with commands to be executed by server

SRC_SV = server.c
SRC_CL = client.c
SRC_HL = network_helpers.c
SRC_CM = example.c

OBJ_CL_FILES = $(SRC_CL:.c=.o)
OBJ_SV_FILES = $(SRC_SV:.c=.o)
OBJ_HL_FILES = $(SRC_HL:.c=.o)
OBJ_CM_FILES = $(SRC_CM:.c=.o)

HL_DIR = ./src/helpers/
CL_DIR = ./src/client/
SV_DIR = ./src/server/
CM_DIR = ./src/server/cmds/
OBJ_DIR = ./obj/
OBJ_CL_DIR = ./obj/client/
OBJ_CM_DIR = ./obj/server/
OBJ_SV_DIR = ./obj/server/
OBJ_HL_DIR = ./obj/helpers/
INC_DIR = ./include/
LIBFT_DIR = ./libft/
SPHX_DIR = ./cmusphinx/

OBJ_CL = $(addprefix $(OBJ_CL_DIR), $(OBJ_CL_FILES))
OBJ_SV = $(addprefix $(OBJ_SV_DIR), $(OBJ_SV_FILES))
OBJ_HL = $(addprefix $(OBJ_HL_DIR), $(OBJ_HL_FILES))
OBJ_CM = $(addprefix $(OBJ_SV_DIR), $(OBJ_CM_FILES))
LIBFT = $(addprefix $(LIBFT_DIR), libft.a)

LINK = -L $(LIBFT_DIR) -lft $(SPHX_LIBS)

all: obj $(LIBFT) $(NAME_CL) $(NAME_SV)

obj:
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_CL_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_SV_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_HL_DIR)

$(OBJ_CL_DIR)%.o:$(CL_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_SV_DIR)%.o:$(SV_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_HL_DIR)%.o:$(HL_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_CM_DIR)%.o:$(CM_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(LIBFT):
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling libft...\033[0m"
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] libft created.\033[0m\n"

$(NAME_CL): $(OBJ_CL) $(OBJ_HL)
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling $(NAME_CL)...\033[0m"
    @gcc $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CL) $(LINK) -lm -o $(NAME_CL)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] $(NAME_CL) Created.\033[0m\n"

$(NAME_SV): $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM)
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling $(NAME_SV)...\033[0m"
    @gcc $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM) $(LINK) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_LIBS) -lm -o $(NAME_SV)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] $(NAME_SV) Created.\033[0m\n"

clean:
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving source objects...\033[0m"
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] Source objects removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving libft objects...\033[0m"
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] libft Objects removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[1;4;91m-----All objects removed!-----\033[0m\n"

clean_client:
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving client objects...\033[0m"
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_CL_DIR)
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_HL_DIR)
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] Client objects removed!\033[0m"

clean_server:
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving server objects...\033[0m"
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_SV_DIR)
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_HL_DIR)
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] Server objects removed!\033[0m"

fclean: clean
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving $(NAME_CL)...\033[0m"
    @rm -f $(NAME_CL)
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] $(NAME_CL) removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving $(NAME_SV)...\033[0m"
    @rm -f $(NAME_SV)
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] $(NAME_SV) removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving libft objects and libft.a...\033[0m"
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) fclean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] libft objects and libft.a removed!!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[1;4;31m-----All objects, executables and lib files removed!-----\033[0m\n"

re: fclean all

.PHONY: clean clean_client clean_server fclean all re
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linker error: "linker input file unused because linking not done", undefined reference to a function in that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395158/linker-error-linker-input-file-unused-because-linking-not-done-undefined-ref)

Comment: The command in tutorial is provided for command-line invocation of the compiler. If you want to use it inside makefile you need to separate linking flags (pkg-config --libs) and compilation flags (pkg-config --cflags) and use them in appropriate places. It is also not a good idea to use shell backticks in makefile, it is not that portable.

Comment: Is there an alternative method to using the backticks? Are they required? I'm only using them because it's how they used it in the tutorial. Also, what about the `DMODELDIR` part? I can easily split up the libs and cflags part, but I'm not sure what to do with the `DMODELDIR`

Comment: I have re-written my original post as to not seem like a duplicate, and I have also spent some time experimenting with the advice you gave me, as well as more googling. I am still unable to get it to compile, but this time the error is different.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of experimentation, I finally figured out the proper way to get my program compiled. Huge thanks to Nikolay, as I would not have been able to solve this without his help. I figured I would post my solution here, just incase anyone else ends up having this same issue, because I found it very difficult to find any resources on how to compile with a Makefile -- the docs tell you how to compile with the terminal, but as Nikolay said, you have to compile in a different way when you are using a Makefile.

This is how I split up the compile arguments

```
MODELDIR = $(shell pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx)
SPHX_FLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags pocketsphinx sphinxbase)
SPHX_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase)

# Variable for linking
LINK = -L $(LIBFT_DIR) -lft $(SPHX_LIBS)
```

And this is how I compiled:

```
#Compiling source to objects here
$(OBJ_CL_DIR)%.o:$(CL_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_SV_DIR)%.o:$(SV_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_HL_DIR)%.o:$(HL_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_CM_DIR)%.o:$(CM_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# Compiling objects to executable here   
$(NAME_SV): $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM)
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling $(NAME_SV)...\033[0m"
    @gcc $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM) $(LINK) $(SPHX_LIBS) -lm -o $(NAME_SV)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] $(NAME_SV) Created.\033[0m\n"
```

Complete Makefile here for reference:

```
NAME_CL = client
NAME_SV = server
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra -g
MODELDIR = $(shell pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx)
SPHX_FLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags pocketsphinx sphinxbase)
SPHX_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase)

# SV - Server specific files
# CL - Client specific files
# HL - Files containing helper functions used in both client and server
# CM - Files with commands to be executed by server

SRC_SV = server.c
SRC_CL = client.c
SRC_HL = network_helpers.c
SRC_CM = example.c

OBJ_CL_FILES = $(SRC_CL:.c=.o)
OBJ_SV_FILES = $(SRC_SV:.c=.o)
OBJ_HL_FILES = $(SRC_HL:.c=.o)
OBJ_CM_FILES = $(SRC_CM:.c=.o)

HL_DIR = ./src/helpers/
CL_DIR = ./src/client/
SV_DIR = ./src/server/
CM_DIR = ./src/server/cmds/
OBJ_DIR = ./obj/
OBJ_CL_DIR = ./obj/client/
OBJ_CM_DIR = ./obj/server/
OBJ_SV_DIR = ./obj/server/
OBJ_HL_DIR = ./obj/helpers/
INC_DIR = ./include/
LIBFT_DIR = ./libft/
SPHX_DIR = ./cmusphinx/

OBJ_CL = $(addprefix $(OBJ_CL_DIR), $(OBJ_CL_FILES))
OBJ_SV = $(addprefix $(OBJ_SV_DIR), $(OBJ_SV_FILES))
OBJ_HL = $(addprefix $(OBJ_HL_DIR), $(OBJ_HL_FILES))
OBJ_CM = $(addprefix $(OBJ_SV_DIR), $(OBJ_CM_FILES))
LIBFT = $(addprefix $(LIBFT_DIR), libft.a)

LINK = -L $(LIBFT_DIR) -lft $(SPHX_LIBS)

all: obj $(LIBFT) $(NAME_CL) $(NAME_SV)

obj:
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_CL_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_SV_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_HL_DIR)

$(OBJ_CL_DIR)%.o:$(CL_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_SV_DIR)%.o:$(SV_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_HL_DIR)%.o:$(HL_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJ_CM_DIR)%.o:$(CM_DIR)%.c
    @gcc -I $(LIBFT_DIR) -I $(INC_DIR) -DMODELDIR=\"$(MODELDIR)\" $(SPHX_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(LIBFT):
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling libft...\033[0m"
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] libft created.\033[0m\n"

$(NAME_CL): $(OBJ_CL) $(OBJ_HL)
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling $(NAME_CL)...\033[0m"
    @gcc $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CL) $(LINK) -lm -o $(NAME_CL)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] $(NAME_CL) Created.\033[0m\n"

$(NAME_SV): $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM)
    @echo "\033[32mCompiling $(NAME_SV)...\033[0m"
    @gcc $(OBJ_SV) $(OBJ_HL) $(OBJ_CM) $(LINK) $(SPHX_LIBS) -lm -o $(NAME_SV)
    @echo "\033[1;4;32m[\xE2\x9C\x94] $(NAME_SV) Created.\033[0m\n"

clean:
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving source objects...\033[0m"
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] Source objects removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving libft objects...\033[0m"
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] libft Objects removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[1;4;91m-----All objects removed!-----\033[0m\n"

clean_client:
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving client objects...\033[0m"
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_CL_DIR)
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_HL_DIR)
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] Client objects removed!\033[0m"

clean_server:
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving server objects...\033[0m"
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_SV_DIR)
    @rm -rf $(OBJ_HL_DIR)
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] Server objects removed!\033[0m"

fclean: clean
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving $(NAME_CL)...\033[0m"
    @rm -f $(NAME_CL)
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] $(NAME_CL) removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving $(NAME_SV)...\033[0m"
    @rm -f $(NAME_SV)
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] $(NAME_SV) removed!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[31mRemoving libft objects and libft.a...\033[0m"
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) fclean
    @echo "\033[4;31m[\xE2\x9D\x8C ] libft objects and libft.a removed!!\033[0m\n"
    @echo "\033[1;4;31m-----All objects, executables and lib files removed!-----\033[0m\n"

re: fclean all

.PHONY: clean clean_client clean_server fclean all re
```